# Determining off to add scale bar and north arrow in spplot

Tags: coordinate-system, r, extents, sf, sp

I have a spplot  in which I want to add north arrow and scale bar.

```
bbox(dis) # dis is my shapefile, an sp object 

        min     max
x -285706.6 1492871
y 2620690.6 4120742
```

I want to attach the north arrow and scale bar. My project UTM 42N

Answer (score 1):

This is more easily achieved with `tmap` (see `tm_compass` and `tm_scale_bar`), or `ggplot + ggspatial` but you would need to rebuild the map.

```
library(sp)


demo(meuse, ask = FALSE, echo = FALSE) # loads the meuse data sets

# Transform
crs.UTM = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=42 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
meuse_UTM = spTransform(meuse, crs.UTM)


spplot(meuse_UTM, "zinc", col.regions=hcl.colors(5,"Plasma"), key.space="right")
```

[image]
`

```
# With tmap
library(tmap)

tm_shape(meuse_UTM) +
  tm_dots(col="zinc", size=.3, palette = hcl.colors(5,"Plasma"), 
          breaks = c(113,459,805,1150,1494,1839)) +
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE, inner.margins = rep(.1,4)) +
  tm_compass(position = c("LEFT","TOP")) +
  tm_scale_bar()
```

[image]

```
# Another option: ggmap + ggspatial
# ggplot2 + ggspatial
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)


ggplot()+
  layer_spatial(meuse_UTM, aes(col=zinc))+
  scale_colour_gradientn(guide = 'legend', colours = hcl.colors(5,"Plasma"),
                         breaks = c(113,459,805,1150,1494,1839)) +
  theme_void() +
  annotation_north_arrow(location="tl", width = unit(.7, "cm"),
                         height = unit(.7, "cm")) +
  annotation_scale(location="br")
```

[image]